# Android erro ao compilar faltando lib - O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Boa noite, eu havia adicionado algumas libs a minha aplicação android, mas depois mudei de ideia e removi as mesmas porem quando vou compilar o codigo está dando o seguinte erro

> Error:Execution failed for task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\felip\AndroidStudioProjects\login\app\libs\httpcore-4.4.4.jar (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado)

ja fiz o refresh de libs ja fiz o clean e nada continua dando este erro alguem sabe o que posso fazer ?

Comment: voce preisa ter esse arquivo "httpcore-4.4.4.jar" na pata "../app/libs" para parar com esse erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marcos, verifique no seu `build.gradle` se existe alguma referência a esta lib, se houver, remova a linha.

Ele estará provavelmente deste jeito:

```
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
```

Após remover a referência, sincronize seu **Gradle** e tente compilar o projeto novamente.

Comment: Ola sua resposta me levou a outro caminho que me ajudou da mesma forma, eu  cliquei encima de app fui em módulos settings e removi as dependências do aplicativo ai compilou, o que ocorreu era o seguinte mesmo tendo  removendo as libs o projeto manteve as libs em  dependência

Comment: Sim Marcos, esqueci de colocar que por aí também dá certo, fico feliz que deu certo, abraço!